# How do I keep the brush radius consistent while moving the camera

Tags: sculpting, texture-painting, brushes

I noticed that when you use the brush tool to paint, sculpt or anything else inside Blender, the brush radius not only depends on the value you give it, but the distance between the camera view and the object you're doing your thing on.

I was wondering if there's any setting where I can actually lock the brush radius so it stays the same size even after zooming into/away from the object.

TLDR: Is the brush radius lockable in reference to scene instead of the viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Brush and select Scene as the Radius Unit.

[image]

Comment: That's true for Sculpt Mode, but not Texture Paint Mode.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Texture Paint Mode?

Comment: Only `Accumulate` and `Affect Alpha` are in that menu in Texture paint Mode.